# Remove trailing white space from elements in a list

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe where a given column is some text. I'm attempting to clean the text and split by comma which would output a new column containing a list of words.

The problem that I'm having is that some of the elements in that list contain trailing white spaces that I would like to remove.

**Code**:

```
# Libraries
# Standard Libraries
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple

# Third Party Libraries
import pyspark
from pyspark.ml.feature import Tokenizer
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as s_function


def tokenize(sdf, input_col="text", output_col="tokens"):
    # Remove email 
    sdf_temp = sdf.withColumn(
        colName=input_col,
        col=s_function.regexp_replace(s_function.col(input_col), "[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+", ""))
    # Remove digits
    sdf_temp = sdf_temp.withColumn(
        colName=input_col,
        col=s_function.regexp_replace(s_function.col(input_col), "\d", ""))
    # Remove one(1) character that is not a word character except for
    # commas(,), since we still want to split on commas(,)
    sdf_temp = sdf_temp.withColumn(
        colName=input_col,
        col=s_function.regexp_replace(s_function.col(input_col), "[^a-zA-Z0-9,]+", " ")) 
    # Split the affiliation string based on a comma
    sdf_temp = sdf_temp.withColumn(
        colName=output_col,
        col=s_function.split(sdf_temp[input_col], ", "))

    return sdf_temp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Sample data
    a_1 = "Department of Bone and Joint Surgery, Ehime University Graduate"\
        " School of Medicine, Shitsukawa, Toon 791-0295, Ehime, Japan."\
        " shinyama@m.ehime-u.ac.jp." 
    a_2 = "Stroke Pharmacogenomics and Genetics, Fundació Docència i Recerca"\
        " Mútua Terrassa, Hospital Mútua de Terrassa, 08221 Terrassa, Spain."
    a_3 = "Neurovascular Research Laboratory, Vall d'Hebron Institute of Research,"\
        " Hospital Vall d'Hebron, 08035 Barcelona, Spain;catycarrerav@gmail.com"\
        " (C.C.). catycarrerav@gmail.com."

    data = [(1, a_1), (2, a_2), (3, a_3)]

    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .master("local[*]")\
        .appName("My_test")\
        .config("spark.ui.port", "37822")\
        .getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

    af_data = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["index", "text"])
    sdf_tokens = tokenize(af_data)
    # sdf_tokens.select("tokens").show(truncate=False)
```

**Output**

```
|[Department of Bone and Joint Surgery, Ehime University Graduate School of Medicine, Shitsukawa, Toon , Ehime, Japan ]                                                |
|[Stroke Pharmacogenomics and Genetics, Fundaci Doc ncia i Recerca M tua Terrassa, Hospital M tua de Terrassa, Terrassa, Spain ]                                       |
|[Neurovascular Research Laboratory, Vall d Hebron Institute of Research, Hospital Vall d Hebron, Barcelona, Spain C C ]
```

**Desired Output**:

```
|[Department of Bone and Joint Surgery, Ehime University Graduate School of Medicine, Shitsukawa, Toon, Ehime, Japan]                                                |
|[Stroke Pharmacogenomics and Genetics, Fundaci Doc ncia i Recerca M tua Terrassa, Hospital M tua de Terrassa, Terrassa, Spain]                                       |
|[Neurovascular Research Laboratory, Vall d Hebron Institute of Research, Hospital Vall d Hebron, Barcelona, Spain C C]
```

so that in the

1. 1st line: `'Toon ' -> 'Toon'`, `'Japan ' -> 'Japan'`.
2. 2nd line: `'Spain ' -> 'Spain'`
3. 3rd line: `'Spain C C ' -> 'Spain C C'`

**Note**

The trailing white spaces do not only appear with the last element of the list, they can occur with any element.

Comment: Your expected output is not python conform - if those should be strings, quote them. It will make it clearer where whitespaces inside strings are - opposed to whitespaces next to colons. Also you have got a `"` too much in your line  `af_data = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["index", ""text"])` quite at the end -  so this code would not even run. please fix. Thanks

Comment: @PatrickArtner when you display a pyspark dataframe with strings using `.show()`, the quotes are omitted.

Comment: @pault - good to know- still for a "desired output" the quotes add a lot of clarity - at least I think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

The original solution won't work because `trim` only operates on the beginning and the end of the entire string, whereas you need it to work on each token.

[@PatrickArtner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972002/5858851) works, but an alternative is to use `RegexTokenizer`.

Here is an example of how you can modify your `tokenize()` function:

```python
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer

def tokenize(sdf, input_col="text", output_col="tokens"):

    # Remove email 
    sdf_temp = sdf.withColumn(
        colName=input_col,
        col=s_function.regexp_replace(s_function.col(input_col), "[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w+", ""))
    # Remove digits
    sdf_temp = sdf_temp.withColumn(
        colName=input_col,
        col=s_function.regexp_replace(s_function.col(input_col), "\d", ""))
    # Remove one(1) character that is not a word character except for
    # commas(,), since we still want to split on commas(,)
    sdf_temp = sdf_temp.withColumn(
        colName=input_col,
        col=s_function.regexp_replace(s_function.col(input_col), "[^a-zA-Z0-9,]+", " "))

    # call trim to remove any trailing (or leading spaces)
    sdf_temp = sdf_temp.withColumn(
        colName=input_col,
        col=s_function.trim(sdf_temp[input_col]))

    # use RegexTokenizer to split on commas optionally surrounded by whitespace
    myTokenizer = RegexTokenizer(
        inputCol=input_col,
        outputCol=output_col,
        pattern="( +)?, ?")

    sdf_temp = myTokenizer.transform(sdf_temp)

    return sdf_temp
```

Essentially, call `trim` on your string to take care of any leading or trailing spaces. Then use the `RegexTokenizer` to split using the pattern `"( +)?, ?"`.

- `( +)?`: match between zero and unlimited spaces
- `,`: match a comma exactly
- `?`: match an optional space

Here is the output of

```python
sdf_tokens.select('tokens', f.size('tokens').alias('size')).show(truncate=False)
```

You can see that the length of the array (number of tokens) is correct, but all of the tokens are lower case (because that's what `Tokenizer` and `RegexTokenizer` do).

```python
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|tokens                                                                                                                        |size|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
|[department of bone and joint surgery, ehime university graduate school of medicine, shitsukawa, toon, ehime, japan]          |6   |
|[stroke pharmacogenomics and genetics, fundaci doc ncia i recerca m tua terrassa, hospital m tua de terrassa, terrassa, spain]|5   |
|[neurovascular research laboratory, vall d hebron institute of research, hospital vall d hebron, barcelona, spain c c]        |5   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
```

---

**Original Answer**

As long as you're using Spark version 1.5 or greater, you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.trim()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.trim) which will:

> Trim the spaces from both ends for the specified string column.

So one way would be to add:

```python
sdf_temp = sdf_temp.withColumn(
        colName=input_col,
        col=s_function.trim(sdf_temp[input_col]))
```

At the end of your `tokenize()` function.

But you may want to instead look into the [`pyspark.ml.feature.Tokenizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#tokenizer) or [`pyspark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer). One idea could be to use your function to clean up your strings, and then use the `Tokenizer` to make the tokens. (I see you've imported it, but don't seem to be using it).

Comment: thats even nicer

Comment: `pyspark.sql.functions.trim(col)` does not remove the spacing from the first line `'Toon '` still has a trailing whitespace.

I didn't even know about `RegexTokenizer` I'll be looking into that. I've been testing `Tokenizer` which is why it's imported but I didn't want to include it in the above code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply replace `' ,'` by `','` and `' $'` by `''` - something along the lines of

```
sdf_temp = sdf_temp.withColumn(
    colName=input_col,
    col=s_function.regexp_replace(s_function.col(input_col), "( ,| $)", ","))
```

That should handle your data.

Depending on your input you might need to replace mutiple spaces, adding a quantifier of '+' will do that.

```
sdf_temp = sdf_temp.withColumn(
    colName=input_col,
    col=s_function.regexp_replace(s_function.col(input_col), "( +,| +$)", ","))
```

right before you split by `', '`.

---

Disclaimer:

just basic regex knowledge - no pyspark specifics.

Comment: @Lukasz, I made an update here that should work for you. Just replace the `" ,"` with `","`. Or you can do a replace of all multiple spaces with a single space. If you do the second code block before you call `split`, this should give you the desired output.

Comment: This method still requires `pyspark.sql.functions.ltrim(col)` before the suggested regex, otherwise the last element in the list will have a comma(,) appended to it.